# how to visualize inflow and outflow of data

Tags: data-visualization

suppose there're 3 items with their respective vol:

```
a b c
12 20 28
```

each has a certain vol added and subtracted

```
   a b c
added 3 5 12
subtracted 2 7 8
```

What format can best visualize the dynamics of inflow and outflow as such, even if number of items are far more than 3?

Comment: It's not clear what you want here, but R is a good tool for visualizing this sort of data, via plots etc.  If you can be more specific about your requirement, maybe someone can given you an answer.

Comment: sorry if it is vague. it wasn't so much about the tool. allow me to explain it another way: say u have 10 bucks, u gained $1 and lost $2, how to translate the whole process into a plot? a grouped bar probably doesn't cut it. stacked bar doubtfully so. what if there's other better options?

Comment: I have an idea: How about a time series plot, where you have a bar for the amount lost or gained.  A gain would be a green bar above the y axis, and a loss would be a red bar below the y axis.  Then, on top of this, you can also plot, as a line graph, the running balance.  This type of thing is used often for financial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, one visualization you could use would actually be a combination of a line chart, to show the running overall trend of the volume, along with a bar for each day, to show the positive or negative gain for that day.  In the financial world, there is already such a chart, called a candlestick chart.  Here is sample of one:

[image]

The way to read the chart is that the circle is where the trend ended in that year.  But the start of the bar (below for losses, above for gains) is where the value actually started in that year.  This is a convenient way to convey both pieces of information which you want to get across to your audience.

Comment: I guess when the gain and loss are simultaneous in each time unit - an example would be the number of people joined and left different teams each month, it's more challenging to convey precisely, but a candlestick is probably one of the closest to describe such.